# Connecting HP Procurve 2626 Switch to PC

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

Hi I use traditional Direct Console cable to connect from HP Switch to PC.
I changed the settings for Putty as well.

This is what documentation says:

> Connect a serial console session with the switch, using the black
>   console cable that would have shipped in the box of any ProCurve
>   switch. The part number of that cable is 5184-1894. The part number is
>   stamped directly on the connectors.
>
> Use a VT100-compliant terminal emulator such as Hyper Terminal or Tera
>   Term Pro to make the serial connection with the switch. Use the
>   following COM port settings to create a terminal session with the
>   Switch 4000m: Any baud rate from 2400 to 115200 (the switch
>   automatically senses the speed). * 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity,
>   XON/XOFF flow control. * For Windows Terminal program, also disable
>   (uncheck) the “Use Function, Arrow, and Ctrl Keys for Windows” option.

I don't know where is disable (uncheck) the “Use Function, Arrow, and Ctrl Keys for Windows” option is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Putty instead!

[image]

[image]

You might need to decrease the speed to 9600 baud on some devices, but the newer HPs with autosensing console lines should handle 115200 baud without a problem, just remember to hit enter two times after you open the session so the switch wakes up the serial session.

Answer (score 0):

It's under `File`->`Properties`->`Settings` in HyperTerminal:

[image]

Comment: I use Putty. My organization doesn't have licence to use HyperTerminal

Comment: Then don't worry about it. HyperTerminal used to be _the_ Windows terminal application, and that is to what the instructions refer.

Comment: If you have a machine with Windows XP, copy C:\Program Files\Windows NT\hypertrm.exe and (same path) hypertrm.dll and you've got yourself Hyperterminal for Win 7, 8, 10.

Answer (score 0):

If your on Linux you can use minicom

```
sudo apt-get install mincom
```

You will also need to add your self to the dialout group

```
$ sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Start minicom as superuser to save config:

```
$ sudo minicom -s
```

For me these options worked:

In minicom:

```
 A - Serial device: /dev/ttyS0
 E - Bps/Par/Bits: 115200 8N1
 F - Hardware Flow Control : No
```

Save setup as dfl. Exit then press enter a few time to get it going. Thats it!

More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto